# Apostrophe in app name

Tags: ios, xcode, apostrophe

I intend on releasing an app in the Apple store that contains an apostrophe in the title. I notice that XCode already has issues in building the code when the 'Target' name contains an apostrophe. I've managed to get around this problem (for now), by using the following character:

```
’
```

as opposed to:

```
'
```

This seems to build okay, but I'm a little concerned about what may happen later down the line, such as when I submit the final build to the store etc.

Does anyone happen to know if this little workaround is suitable, or am I just setting myself up for a world of problems?

For example, is using an abstract character like this going to mean no one can *search* for my app in the store?

Comment: Do you have to escape it (`\'`)?

Comment: Maybe, but I still wonder what the effect might be later on. I wouldn't want the backslash appearing in the app store!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The display name of the app as it will appear on the iOS spring board is set in the app's infoPlist and has nothing to do with build settings. The Xcode project, target and all other files can be named whatever you like.

You need to set the `CFBundleDisplayName` in your app's Info.plist. By default this is set to `${PRODUCT_NAME}` which is the Xcode configuration variable of the target's name, but it can be what you like.

Going one step further you should use the `InfoPlist.strings` file to overload this value for different localisations. Setting the value in this file will make the other value in the Info.plist obsolete. These days Xcode comes with a blank one in new projects but it's easily added if it's not there.

The InfoPlist.strings file would look like this:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "App's Name";
```

**Note:** If you've set up the app's name as above and the spring board isn't displaying the Apostrophe then it's probably taking it out deliberately.

Comment: Will the CFBundleDisplayName also be the same name shown in the Apple store? Will users be able to search for my app even if they omit the apostrophe from their search term? Trying to work out if I'm shutting out potential users searching for my app by including the apostrophe...

Comment: No, the app display name on the App Store is set when you create the app entry in iTunes Connect.

Comment: @CaptainProg You're talking about the name in the App Store!? Just type it in! that's got even less to do with the code!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're talking about the title of your application in The App Store, which is entered in iTunes Connect and has **absolutely nothing to do with any code you write.**

If you place an apostrophe in your app's name in iTunes connect it may have an effect on the users searching for your app as you suspect.but often apps have extended names that offer more context to the app's name and you should also use the **keywords** to your advantage.

You should check out the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/1_Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `CFBundleDisplayName` in info.plist to

```
<string>App&apos;s Name</string>
```

Works perfectly. I've used above in production app, with no issues.