# Apostrophe in NativeScript App name is not working for Android/ios deployment

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

I am working on a NativeScript App and I want to publish that APP on google play store with an apostrophe('s) in it's Name e.g. Naren's App.
It is working fine on ios as I have to change info.plist file as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060330/apostrophe-in-app-name) example.
But for Android it is trimimng the name after ('s) and it is deployed on device/emulator as Naren not Naren's App.

Here is the code in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

and in strings.xml(in values and values-v21 folder)

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Naren's Orders Dev</string>
    <string name="title_activity_kimera">Naren's Orders Dev</string>
</resources>
```

Has anyone experienced it before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution on android resources [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#FormattingAndStyling). They say

**Handle special characters**

When a string contains characters that have special usage in XML or Android, you must escape the characters. Some characters can be escaped by using a preceding backslash, while others require XML escaping. Apostrophes and single quotes can also be handled by enclosing the entire string in double quotes. Some examples are shown below:

**Single quote (')**
Any of the following:

```
&apos;

\'

Enclose the entire string in double quotes ("This'll work", for example)
```

I have tried with  `&apos;` first but that was **not** working but `\'s` is working. Posting it here as it may be useful for others.

EDIT:

`&apos;` is working with ios but it is trimming down white space for that `Replace normal space with unicode &#x2007;`